# Ajax call to insert to database not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax call on button click to insert to a database through a PHP file. I want to use AJAX to achieve this, but it does not show the alert dialog on success nor does it insert the data to the database. Here is the code I have:

AjaxTest.html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="create()">Click me</button>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
 function create () {
   $.ajax({
      url: "AjaxTestRegistration.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'bid': 10,
        'kid': 20
        },

        success: function (msg) {
            alert("!");
        }
        });
  }
</script>
```

AjaxTestRegistration.php:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
include "Coupon.php";


$bid = $_GET['bid'];
$kid = $_GET['kid'];
Coupon::insertCoupon($bid, $kid);

?>
```

If I try to enter AjaxTestRegistration.php manually in the browser like this: ajaxtestregistration.php?kid=10&bid=5, the row gets inserted into the database.
wWhat could be the problem with this code? How to rectify that?

Comment: Voting to close as "typo or similar": mismatch between `type: "POST",` and `$_GET['bid'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP handles `GET` requests.

```
$bid = $_GET['bid'];
```

But your ajax function tries to `POST`

```
type: "POST",
```

The easiest here is to get your data by `$_POST` in php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `$__REQUEST` method of php and also use `$_POST` method if you use post from ajax

```
$bid = $__REQUEST['bid'];
$kid = $__REQUEST['kid'];
```